# Silverlight custom shape region with settable background color

Tags: silverlight, blend, region

I want to have a region element on my silverlight window that I can set a foreground color to.

My questions are:

1. Which tool should I use to draw a custom shape region (in my case in need it to be in a form of a raindrop)?
2. How will I set a color to a shape whenever I have a XAML declaration for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with Expression Design. :)

I just drew something (well let's call it a raindrop lol) in Expression Design and exported it to Expression Blend as a path object,

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 507.262,234.751C 537.262,324.251 561.008,330.866 561.008,364.002C 561.008,397.137 534.146,423.999 501.011,423.999C 467.876,423.999 441.014,397.137 441.014,364.002C 441.014,330.866 497.071,204.348 507.262,234.751 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131.514,83.574,0,201.502" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="120.994"/>
```

You can change its background color by modifying its Fill property.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you. Here is a simple HEX to Color converter that helps to see what color does particular hex code represent: http://maxpavlov.com/page/hextocolor.aspx The good thing is that it works with WPF/SL long codes, when, Paint.net color picker control doesn't allow it.